# database error on schema validate with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, schema

I'm attempting to create a database using the doctrine orm with an application built by someone else. I'm getting Database errors, and I'm unsure if I'm unclear on the concept, or if I need to adjust the Annotations.

Command and output:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

Mapping
-------


[OK] The mapping files are correct.


Database
--------

15:06:28 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:validate". Message: "Invalid index-name unique_organization_id_application_id given, has to be [a-zA-Z0-9_]" ["error" => Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException { …},"command" => "doctrine:schema:validate","message" => "Invalid index-name unique_organization_id_application_id given, has to be [a-zA-Z0-9_]"] []


[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
Invalid index-name unique_organization_id_application_id given, has to be [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

It almost sounds like the database isn't set up properly(though I thought this was the first step before setting up the database schema)

The annotation:

```
@ORM\Table(name="applications", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="﻿unique_organization_id_application_id", columns={"organization_id", "application_id"})})
```

And this is where I'm out of my depth. `organizationId` and `applicationId` are both private members(?) of the class, with getters and setters. `﻿unique_organization_id_application_id` isn't found anywhere in the class.

Comment: What's the output of `php bin/console doctrine:schema:diff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invalid index-name unique_organization_id_application_id given, has to be [a-zA-Z0-9_]

The error says that you inserted some non-english letters in the index name. Try to completly remove the name.

Comment: I typed in the sting "unique_organization_id_application_id" and the diffed the file. Turns out there was a hidden character <U+FEFF>. What a catch!